# AVAudioSession cannot set "inputGain" for microphone on bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, avaudiosession

With mic on bluetooth headset, it seems we cannot set "inputGain" value by the method below

```
class: AVAudioSession  method: -(BOOL)setInputGain:(float)gain error:(NSError **)outError
```

The default value of "inputGain" for bluetooth headset is about 0.5

But I encounter a strange case that:

1. With built-in microphone on iPhone (default value is 0.142857), I use the method above to set the "inputGain" value to 0.8  It's OK
2. Then I connect the bluetooth headset. I check the "inputGain" value, it show 0.8. Very strange, it's not 0.5 now, it seem the value of built-in mic.

   After that, although I re-connect or restart the bluetooh headset, the value is still 0.8

I repeat those 2 steps above with any value in range of inputGain (0.0 to 1.0), the results is the same. Very strange with microphone on bluetooth headset.

My question is:

- I see the "inputGain" value for bluetooth headset can be changed. So how do I change that?
- After changing for bluetooth headset, the "inputGain" value keep intact. How do I revert it to default value?

Thank you!